# pyspark toPandas() IndexError: index is out of bounds

Tags: pandas, pyspark, index-error

I'm experiencing a weird behaviour of pyspark's .toPandas() method running from Jupyt. For example, if I try this:

```
data = [{"Category": 'Category A', "ID": 1, "Value": 12.40},
        {"Category": 'Category B', "ID": 2, "Value": 30.10},
        {"Category": 'Category C', "ID": 3, "Value": 100.01}
        ]

# Create data frame (where spark is a SparkSession)
df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
df.show()
```

I'm able to successfully create the pyspark dataframe. However, when converting to pandas I get *IndexError: index is out of bounds*:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<path_to_python>/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    700                 type_pprinters=self.type_printers,
    701                 deferred_pprinters=self.deferred_printers)
--> 702             printer.pretty(obj)
    703             printer.flush()
    704             return stream.getvalue()

<path_to_python>/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/lib/pretty.py in pretty(self, obj)
    400                         if cls is not object \
    401                                 and callable(cls.__dict__.get('__repr__')):
--> 402                             return _repr_pprint(obj, self, cycle)
    403 
    404             return _default_pprint(obj, self, cycle)

<path_to_python>/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/lib/pretty.py in _repr_pprint(obj, p, cycle)
    695     """A pprint that just redirects to the normal repr function."""
    696     # Find newlines and replace them with p.break_()
--> 697     output = repr(obj)
    698     for idx,output_line in enumerate(output.splitlines()):
    699         if idx:

<path_to_python>/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py in __repr__(self)
     76         Yields Bytestring in Py2, Unicode String in py3.
     77         """
---> 78         return str(self)
     79 
     80 

<path_to_python>/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py in __str__(self)
     55 
     56         if compat.PY3:
---> 57             return self.__unicode__()
     58         return self.__bytes__()
     59 

<path_to_python>/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __unicode__(self)
    632             width = None
    633         self.to_string(buf=buf, max_rows=max_rows, max_cols=max_cols,
--> 634                        line_width=width, show_dimensions=show_dimensions)
    635 
    636         return buf.getvalue()

<path_to_python>/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in to_string(self, buf, columns, col_space, header, index, na_rep, formatters, float_format, sparsify, index_names, justify, max_rows, max_cols, show_dimensions, decimal, line_width)
    719                                            decimal=decimal,
    720                                            line_width=line_width)
--> 721         formatter.to_string()
    722 
    723         if buf is None:

<path_to_python>/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py in to_string(self)
    596         else:
    597 
--> 598             strcols = self._to_str_columns()
    599             if self.line_width is None:  # no need to wrap around just print
    600                 # the whole frame

<path_to_python>/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py in _to_str_columns(self)
    527                 str_columns = [[label] for label in self.header]
    528             else:
--> 529                 str_columns = self._get_formatted_column_labels(frame)
    530 
    531             stringified = []

<path_to_python>/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py in _get_formatted_column_labels(self, frame)
    770                             need_leadsp[x] else x]
    771                            for i, (col, x) in enumerate(zip(columns,
--> 772                                                             fmt_columns))]
    773 
    774         if self.show_row_idx_names:

<path_to_python>/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    769             str_columns = [[' ' + x if not self._get_formatter(i) and
    770                             need_leadsp[x] else x]
--> 771                            for i, (col, x) in enumerate(zip(columns,
    772                                                             fmt_columns))]
    773 

<path_to_python>/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py in _get_formatter(self, i)
    362         else:
    363             if is_integer(i) and i not in self.columns:
--> 364                 i = self.columns[i]
    365             return self.formatters.get(i, None)
    366 

<path_to_python>/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   3956         if is_scalar(key):
   3957             key = com.cast_scalar_indexer(key)
-> 3958             return getitem(key)
   3959 
   3960         if isinstance(key, slice):

IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3
```

I'm not sure where the problem can be, I've used this many times without problems but this time I tried a new environment and I got this issue. In case it can help my configuration is:

> Python: 3.7.6;
> Pandas: 0.24.2;
> PySpark: 2.4.5

Any idea?
Thanks :)

Comment: Can you rename the ID column and try again?

Comment: @LuizViola thanks for the suggestion. I actually found the error and posted the fix below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. Trying to minimize the code to reproduce the error I omitted that  I was adding a pandas setting:

> pd.set_option('display.max_columns', -1)

This caused the error independently of the dataframe being converted. To fix it I just specified a positive number of columns or None.